# How to repair obstructed directories in working copies

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an application which keeps its data in a directory tree.

Now, I want to keep this directory under version control with svn.

The problem is, however, that this application from time to time deletes and recreates some directories in this tree, which leads to the appropriate .svn subdirectories to be lost, and TortoiseSVN then loudly complains about obstructed directories.

Is there any special option, script (cygwin batch, windows cmd, python...) or program that can repair those working copies? Currently, I'm using a directory synchronization tool to re-add the lost .svn files from a second working copy, but that is very cumbersome.

Thanks!

Comment: SVN is very limited in managing directory changes like this.  If it's an option for your project, I'd strongly suggest looking at git.

Comment: @payne: Sorry, git currently is not an option. I also read that the svn developers plan to change their working copy format to a global directory in the working copy root. But in the meantime, a script or something that simply recreates the .svn subdirectories would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't repair what's lost.

The folders are gone, and they can't just be recreated out of thin air. The only way to get them back again is to run an update, but that requires that the whole folders are first removed since an update doesn't overwrite existing files.

Comment: But all the information is there, in the SVN repository, no need to create it out of thin air. A fresh checkout and then manually copying all the .svn directories from each subdirectory from the fresh checkout to my working copy solves the problem (but is cumbersome). The application does not restructure the directories in any way, it just deletes some of the subdirectories and recreates them identically (minus some modified data files).

Comment: I'll accept that answer, although it does not solve my problem. In the meantime, the problem was solved by an update of the application which does not delete the directories any more, and SVN 1.7 would have solved the problem by not needing .svn subdirs in every directory.

Comment: The answer misses the point completely. I have a similar application (Mendeley Desktop) and it deletes and recreates directories. I don't want to restore them, just make SVN add them as if they were not already under version control, creating a new .svn subdirectory in them and (when committed) overwriting whatever was in the previous version.

Answer (score 17):

I renamed the conflicting folder and ran an SVN update to restore the folder from SVN.

After diffing with my favorite diff tool (Synchronize directories in Total Commander), i see that the only difference was that the conflicting folder had an .svn folder in it.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I had an svn folder in the sub-directory, and it didn't need to be there. I deleted it, then ran an svn update on the parent folder like I wanted, and it versioned the files in the subdirectory.

Comment: This is what happened to me, I deleted a folder, and the .svn subfolder was deleted. I did what Cees T said, and got my old files, then moved the new ones into the restored via update one. Voila! THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for obstructed directories while SVN commit could be when IDE like Visual Studio deletes and recreates output directories thereby removing .svn folders. So build this VS project somewhere else and then overwrite to the original checked out place to preserve the .svn folders. Then do SVN add and SVN commit.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on "TortoiseSVN > Clean up..." (all options were ticked except "Revert all changes recursively").
After that I did a "SVN Update" and the issue was gone.

Answer (score -1):

My issue was with Visual SVN within VS, it had lost its bindings although evreything was fine when last I committed. Deleted the .svn folder in the project root folder on disk, and updated. Everything back to normal again as in Andy's answer above.